# Using QGIS how to extract single polygon co-ordinates in multiple polygon data?

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, select-by-attribute, geolocation

I have polygon coordinates for complete India at district level and I want to just use 2 or 3 districts out of complete polygon.

For example : I want to just select district Pune and Nasik and need this two polygon coordinates, but there are 100 district polygon boundaries in .shp file.

How to extract only selected district polygon coordinates ?

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates"? Do you want to extract those districts into a new file or do you need a plain text list of their coordinates?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I want to extract Nasik and Pune district into a new file

Comment: @bugmenot123, just like filter this two district and that will save in new file, and ones i open that new file it will just show polygon for this two district only

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110352/save-selection-option-in-qgis-2-4-0 :)

Comment: @bugmenot123 , but that option I cant click :( , that option is in black color, not possible to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter the two districts of interest using an expression like this (`"District"` is the name of the field which stores the strings `Nasik` and `Pune`, so adapt it to your case):

[image]

Once you have done this, right click on the layer and select `"Save As"`. In the save layer dialog make sure the check box `"Save only selected features"` is checked.

Comment: how to see my variable name , I am not sure in this .shp file there will be variable name is use "District"  ?

Comment: I have variable name :  ID_0 ISO NAME_0 ID_1 NAME_1 ID_2 NAME_2 HASC_2 CCN_2 CCA_2 TYPE_2 ENGTYPE_2 NL_NAME_2 VARNAME_2
so, NAME_1= "Nasik' or 'NAME_1 ='Pune' ?

Comment: @KiranPrajapati yes, if you see them under the `NAME_1` field.